# Kendo Grid Detail Template two level deep - deepest grid sometimes not binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a weird problem with Detail Template in Kendo Grid.  I have two level deep of Detail Templates and it has been working most of the time (as weird as that sounds).  Sometimes the deepest grid doesn´t bind the data from the server without any errors.  When examining Firebug I can see that the Json response is clearly responding with correct data, however the grid doesn´t bind the data (at least the css class shows "t-no-data" in the markup).  Let me be clear though, this only happens sometimes, not always.  I´ve been trying to make out any pattern in when this happens but haven´t been able to spot any.  Here is an example of my code:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DepObject>()
        .Name("DepartmentGrid")
        .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Bound(e => e.DepartmentCode).Hidden();
                c.Bound(e => e.DepartmentName);
            })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("CesTmp")
        .DataSource(d => d.Ajax().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.DepartmentCode)))
        .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
        )
</div>
<script id="CesTmp" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CesObject>()
        .Name("CesGrid_#=DepartmentCode#")
        .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Bound(e => e.CesCode).Hidden();
                c.Bound(e => e.CesName);
            })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("ItemTmp")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetCesData", "Cesce", new { depCode = "#=DepartmentCode#" }).Data("filterCes")).Model(m => m.Id(p => p.CesCode))
                .Events(ev => ev.Error("onErrorCes"))
                )
        .ToClientTemplate()
        )
</script>
<script id="ItemTmp" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ItemObject>()
        .Name("ItemGrid_#=CesCode#")
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Item).Hidden();
                columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Encoded(false);
            })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemData", "Cesce", new { depCode = "#=DepartmentCode#", cesceCode = "#=CesCode#" }).Data("filterItem"))
                .Events(ev => ev.Error("onErrorCes"))
        )
        .ToClientTemplate()
        )
</script>
```

**Does anyone have any idea what could cause this strange behaviour?**

Comment: maybe you could try to reproduce this with the generated javascript (then you could do manual ajax requests in the read action and log the data and other things which might help diagnose this); have you tried debugging in the browser? e.g. to see what the .success method gets called with and what happens afterwards? (ideally with the unminified Kendo UI source)

Comment: Please be sure that always your grids Ids (Name) are unique. Check this behaviour in different browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys.  I think I found a solution to this particular problem, but I found it difficult to debug, but in the end the solution was of course quite simple.
I will create an answer for this later on, but I will up you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I stumbled on a pattern.  The deepest grid, the CesceCode-grid, is displaying data with the same CesceCode depending on which Department is selected.  Therefore, I had to create more complicated ID for the grid, the grid ID wasn´t unique if user has clicked cesce grid with the same ID.  Instead of using only CesceCode og also added DepartmentCode to create more complicated ID.  Here´s an example of the script I use to grab the grid:

```
var itemDetailGrid = $("#itemCostGrid_" + DepartmentCode + CesceCode).data("kendoGrid");
```

Anyway, what I should have done with the declaration client side should have been something like this:

```
<script id="ItemTmp" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ItemObject>()
    .Name("ItemGrid_#=DepartmentCode##=CesCode#") // <-- this is the new name
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Item).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Encoded(false);
        })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemData", "Cesce", new { depCode = "#=DepartmentCode#", cesceCode = "#=CesCode#" }).Data("filterItem"))
            .Events(ev => ev.Error("onErrorCes"))
    )
    .ToClientTemplate()
    )
```

Thanks for all your input guys  :)

Comment: @Majid nice to hear  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug after activating "Show Threads In Source" button.

I had many weird problems because of this thread structure. Maybe order of read functions inverted.

Just an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @user2688655 but I stumbled upon the solution.  I will create an answer on this thread later today  :)
I will up your answer for your trouble.